# Is it possible to give specific color for stacks on Bar graph in dimple.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have drawn barchart using dimple.js. My graph contains different number of stacks and i have ordered it in my own order. How can i give a specific color to the top stack of the graph is it possible to give a specific color to a specific stack in the graph?

for example :

```
var data = [{
    "Brand":"A", 
    "Day":"Mon", 
    "SalesVolume":10 },
    { 
    "Brand":"B", 
    "Day":"Mon", 
    "SalesVolume":20 },
    { 
    "Brand":"C", 
    "Day":"Mon", 
    "SalesVolume":20 },
    { 
    "Brand":"D", 
    "Day":"Mon", 
    "SalesVolume":20 },
    { 
    "Brand":"E", 
    "Day":"Mon",
    "SalesVolume":20 },
    {  
    "Brand":"F", 
    "Day":"Mon", 
    "SalesVolume":10 }];
```

In my case the stack F will come on top as per my ordering. So i have to give a specific color to that stack alone. how to achieve this?

I tried using d3.js but i couldnt achieve that. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use the chart's `assignColor` method.

https://github.com/PMSI-AlignAlytics/dimple/wiki/dimple.chart#assignColor